# Is iterator range vector construction or vector erase faster?

Tags: c++

Consider these two different implementations of a function which drops `x` elements from the front:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> drop(int size, const std::vector<T>& coll){
    if (size<0) return std::vector<T>();
    auto sized = size > coll.size() ? coll.size() : size;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator first = coll.begin()+sized;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator last = coll.end();
    return std::vector<T>(first,last);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> drop2(int size, std::vector<T> coll){
    if (size<0) return std::vector<T>();
    auto sized = size > coll.size() ? coll.size() : size;
    coll.erase(coll.begin(),coll.begin()+sized);
    return coll;
}
```

In both versions, a new `std::vector` is allocated (in the second, it is copied as an argument, which is not a reference). In one, the result is created by `erase()` while in the other the result is created using the iterators of the original vector.

Is there any reason to believe that one of these would be meaningfully different in performance than the other?

Also, is RVO a guarantee in either or both of these?

EDIT:

Here is a test I did, which shows the first one is quite a bit *slower* than the second:

```
template<typename F>
void dropExample(F f){
    std::cout<<"drop example"<<std::endl;
    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    for (auto x: range(100000)){
        f(2, range(100));
    }
    auto t2 = Clock::now();

    std::cout << "Delta t2-t1: "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
    << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
dropExample(drop<int>);
dropExample(drop2<int>);

drop example 
Delta t2-t1: 625 ms
drop example 
Delta t2-t1: 346 ms
```

No matter how many iterations I add to the `for` loop, the numbers are approximately like this, even for operations into the tens of seconds.

EDIT 2:

I have augmented the test with lvalue, as suggested in comments:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
void dropExample2(F f, T vec){
    std::cout<<"drop example 2"<<std::endl;
    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    for (auto x: range(1000)){
        f(2, vec);
    }
    auto t2 = Clock::now();

    std::cout << "Delta t2-t1: "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
    << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Then in main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto testrange=range(100000);

    dropExample(drop<int>);
    dropExample(drop2<int>);

    dropExample2(drop<int>,testrange);
    dropExample2(drop2<int>,testrange);

     return 0;
}
```

Output still suggests the second is much faster:

```
drop example 
Delta t2-t1: 564 ms
drop example 
Delta t2-t1: 375 ms
drop example 2 
Delta t2-t1: 2318 ms
drop example 2 
Delta t2-t1: 698 ms
```

Here are supplementary functions used in the example:

```
std::vector<int> range(int start, int end, int step);

std::vector<int> range(int start, int end){
    if (end<start){
        return range(start,end,-1);
    }else if (start == end){
        return std::vector<int> {start};
    }else{
        std::vector<int> nums(end-start);
        std::iota(nums.begin(),nums.end(),start);
        return nums;}
}

std::vector<int> range(int end){
    return range(0,end);
}

std::vector<int> range(int start, int end, int step){
    std::vector<int> nums{start};
    auto next=start+step;
    while ((next<end&&start<=end&&step>0)||
           (next>end&&start>end&&step<0))
    {
        nums.push_back(next);
        next+=step;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: The first is almost certainly faster than the second.

Comment: I think it would be meaningful to work on actual performance data, analyzed by a profiler, rather than just guessing.

Comment: There are no guarantees the RVO will be used.  The compiler may do it but that is all you can know until you compile it and find out.

Comment: @NathanOliver There's still no guaranteed RVO in C++17. There is a *proposal* to do that that has passed EWG.

Comment: @T.C. Oops.  I thought it made in.  edited comment.

Comment: @T.C. interesting guess... using std::chrono to time each over millions of operations, the first always takes at least 50% longer, often nearly twice as long.

Comment: @johnbakers How are you compiling?

Comment: With the test example, the supplied vector is a temporary, and the function calls `erase` directly on the supplied vector. Since erase is probably a bunch of move operations and *might* be copy operations, it's going to be faster. Try supplying an l-value. Since you're dealing with `int` it's just copy operations. *However* the second test doesn't need to allocate memory.

Comment: Please show us the whole test you ran, including the `main()`, otherwise we won't know for sure if we're running the same test as you are.

Comment: @jaggedSpire updated with lvalue test

Comment: @T.C. updated with full test

Comment: What is `range` and `logit`?  We need a compile-able example.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25c8a2b8f67c321f

Comment: @NathanOliver I have added the range function code, and removed logit

Comment: @T.C. most of your results are much closer between the two than mine. I'm on clang c++14 OSX if that matters. My drop2 is always much faster, nearly double the speed for some reason. I agree it would seem the first drop should be faster.

Comment: Also, only dropping two elements is a very good scenario for drop2, since the amount of unnecessary copies is minimal.

Comment: @johnbakers What are the flags you are using to compile?

Comment: @T.C. no matter how I tweak the number of elements in the vector, the number get dropped (i've tried hundreds as the drop parameter), no change seems to make the first one faster. weird.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm in Xcode and it says `-std=c++14` and `libc++`

Comment: @johnbakers what is the number after `-O`?

Comment: @jaggedSpire honestly i don't know, my IDE handles these options I cannot find any `-0` setting anywhere. I'll have to investigate. what does that setting mean?

Comment: @johnbakers it controls how/if the code is optimized.

Comment: and is very important to know.

Comment: @jaggedSpire for what it's worth, I tried switching the compiler between debug and release modes, with same general ratios of time between the two functions.

Comment: @jaggedSpire according to the LLVM Code Generation settings, for Debug there is shown None [-O0) and for Release it shows -Os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example will create a whole bunch of objects (in copying the input parameter) just to get rid of them later (at the call to erase).  The performance difference because of that will depend on what `T` is, but I doubt the first one would ever be slower.
Also the amount of memory used will be greater in the second version as erase does not reallocate memory.

**EDIT**
Your current test is flawed because you pass the vector to be subsetted as a temporary, allowing the compiler to move construct the input parameter in `drop2` and thus eliding the copy completely.  Simply changing:

```
   for (auto x: range(100000))
       f(200, range(10000));
```

to

```
   auto v = range(10000);
   for (auto x: range(100000))
       f(200, v);
```

Changed the results around quite dramatically.  However, the second method was still faster for me until the vectors were much larger.  It's also worth noting that because you are using `int` the different methods could be optimally optimized to `memcpy` and a couple of pointer manipulations.

`drop` could become simply a memcpy of `(coll.size() - size) * sizeof(int)` bytes while `drop2` could become a memcpy of `coll.size() * sizeof(int)` bytes.  This is because the destructor for an `int` is a no op and so the call to erase could become simply subtracting `size` from the `__last` pointer of the vector.

If all you are interested in is primitive types like this then that's okay, but if you also want to have an optimal implementation for, say, `std::string` then its destructor and copy-constructor become very important factors.  I have tried with `std::vector<int>` as the type inside the vector and, while being slower overall, for smaller sizes it seems that `drop2` is still faster.  `drop` becomes more efficient at a lower threshold, however.  I very much doubt that that is what we are seeing here, so the code we end up running is in some sort of in-between state of being just `memcpy`'s and being what we wrote verbatim.

I guess in the end we are testing the compiler's ability to optimize different functions (`std::uninitialized_copy`, `std::move`(the iterator-based one), calling `get_allocator().destroy(p)` in a loop on trivial and non-trivial types, etc...).  All I can say at this point is that results can vary quite wildly in terms of what gets optimized and by how much for even seemingly small changes in the code.

I am, however, still surprised the `drop2` runs faster than `drop`, even if only for ranges under a certain size.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is almost certainly faster, unless you are feeding `drop` an rvalue, in which case you'd have to measure.

Suppose you have N elements to start with, and M elements to drop:

- The first copies N-M elements; the second copies N elements.
- The first performs no assignment; the second performs N-M move assignments, which may degenerate to copy assignments.
- The first may, and in practice will, RVO. The second one requires a move that cannot be elided. However, moving vectors are sufficiently cheap that the extra cost is likely minimal.

Comment: I have updated with a test results, suggesting the second is actually much faster.

Comment: after playing quite a bit with the test settings in my test example, i was finally able to create scenarios where the first one was faster, only when the vector being operated on pre-drop was 10 million elements in size. But, the first one was only faster if the vector was an lvalue. the second remained fastest in all other tests regardless of size.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the answer lies in an extensive benchmark of the two versions.

However, making an assessment, I tend to believe that the first version is going to be faster, due to the fact that in the general case you have to copy less elements from the initial vector to the output vector, than in the second one where you copy them all.